# What causes run time error in the following program?

Tags: c++

I am using this simple function to create a new node

```
node* Tree::createNewNode(int score, const char* word)
{
    // Create a new node with the information available 
    node* n = new node;
    n->left=NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->parent = NULL;
    n->score = score;
    strcpy(n->word,word);
    return n;
}
```

node is a structure:

```
struct node
{
  int score; // the score or label of the node
  char *word; // the word stored in the node
  node *left; // the pointer to left child of the node
  node *right; // the pointer to right child of the node
  node *parent; // the pointer to parent node
};
```

And I am calling the createNewNode function from another function

```
temp = t->createNewNode(score,"");
```

The function runs properly for only one time and then it crashes while executing:

```
node* n = new node;
```

Comment: I would recommend not following the advice in the two answers given and using `std::string` and constructors rather than legacy C functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to the `word` field. You are trying to copy data into `word` with out allocating space for it.

change `char *word` to `char word[100];`

Comment: And then he should use strncpy(n->word, word, 100 - 1) so that he does not overflow the word buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *word;     // this is a pointer to string, aka this is not a string
char word[100]; // this is a string
```

`n->word` is uninitialized. when you are using `strcpy` you are copying `word` content in an unknown address.

This result on unknown behavior (The first call look like it work and the second made the program crash). You need to allocate the memory space to hold `word` string inside the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to `word` not being allocated memory.

You could fix this using legacy C functionality like in the other answers, or you could actually write idomatic C++.

All of the initialization done in the `createNewNode` function should be done in the `node` constructor. You should use `std::string` instead of `char*` to avoid memory allocation failures like you currently have. You should also protect the members of your `node` class, instead providing mutators to attach/detach them from the tree so you don't need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashes in the following line,

```
strcpy(n->word,word);
```

because, `n->word` in `struct node`

```
char *word; // the word stored in the node
```

was not allocated any memory.

Use `char array` instead of `char pointer` or change the function definition like this:

```
node* createNewNode(int score, const char* word, int wordLen)
{                                                     ^^^^ 
    // Create a new node with the information available
    node* n = new node;
    n->left=NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->parent = NULL;
    n->score = score;
    n->word = (char *) malloc(wordLen);
    strcpy(n->word,word);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy(n->word, word)` copies the input string into `n->word` which has not been initialized. For that experession to work correcly `n->word` must point to an allocated buffer.

`strdup` function allocates that buffer for you and copies the input string into that buffer, e.g.:

```
n->word = strdup(word);
```